# Error with src() command in R

Tags: r

Yesterday I posted [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32582/interpreting-a-weak-model-proceeding-from-there) on Stats Exchange and based on the response I got, I decided to do some analysis using R's src() function. It's part of the "sensitivity" package.

I installed the package with no trouble, and then tried the following command:

```
sens <- src(seminars, REV, rank=TRUE, nboot=100)
```

`sens` is a new variable to store the results of the test

`seminars` is a data frame that I imported from a CSV file using the `read.csv()` command

`REV` is the name of a variable/column in `seminars` and my desired response variable

When I ran the command, I got the following error:

```
Error in data.frame(Y = y, X) : object 'REV' not found
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you post the results of `dput(seminars)` (or perhaps `dput(head(seminars))` if it is a large dataframe)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of src

```
   y: a vector containing the responses corresponding to the design
      of experiments (model output variables).
```

The input needs to be a vector (apparently) and you're attempting to pass in a name (and not even quoting the name at that).  Since REV isn't defined (I'm guessing due to the error message) in the global environment it doesn't know what to do.

From reading the documentation it sounds like what you want to do is pass `sensitivity[,-which(colnames(sensitivity) == "REV")]` (just the design matrix - you don't want to include the responses) in as x and `sensitivity[,"REV"]` in as y.

Comment: Ahh, that was the problem. I ended up extracting REV as a vector and then deleting it from the data frame before running it all again. Unfortunately, now I'm having another problem. I have another set of the same data in which I've dummy-coded some of the variables in a particular way that's important to my analysis. When I run the test with that set of data, though, I get:


    Error in if (const(t, min(1e-08, mean(t, na.rm = TRUE)/1e+06))) { : 
    missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: You should make a new question for that.  But it sounds like what you're evaluating ends up being empty.  It's not really possible to diagnose without more info.  Also if my answer helped feel free to upvote it and accept it as correct.  If somebody else comes along with a better answer you can always unaccept mine and then accept theirs.

Comment: I can't upvote as I'm new on the site, but I accepted your answer.

Comment: Well I can't provide an answer to something that isn't posted as a question so that would at least be a first step.

Answer (score 0):

This error is linked to the fact that the data.frame X=seminars include factors with 0 value, which produce an error while constructing the regression coefficient. You can first remove them as they don't contribute to the variance of the output.